# Can't Store Res in Session in Nextjs

Tags: session, next.js, next-auth

I'm setting up Next.js application and implementing custom Discord login.

Once user is redirected to website (localhost for now, specifically /pages/api/auth/redirect/discord.ts), discord.ts is fired that gets the token from response, exchanges for access token and fetches user data I need as json object and stores it in a variable called `combinedData`. At last, user is redirected to index page '/'.

I need to store this `combinedData` in a session so once user is redirected, I can access the data globally, save it as a cookie so user doesn't have to log in again etc.

This is the middleware:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import withSession from 'next-session';

const sessionConfig = {
  name: 'Discord session',
  secret: 'rKweJkORLDFP4w65AGlXEzsjbZ90RVLp',
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // Expires in 7 days
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    sameSite: true,
  },
  rolling: true,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
};

const sessionMiddleware = withSession(sessionConfig);

const withSessionMiddleware = (handler: (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => Promise<void>) => {
    return async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
        await sessionMiddleware(req, res); // Call session middleware first.
        return handler(req, res); // Then call your handler.
    };
};
```

export default withSessionMiddleware;`

This is discord.ts

```
interface NextApiRequestWithSession extends NextApiRequest {
  session?: any;  // Ideally, replace any with your session's type if you know it.
}

const redirect = async (req: NextApiRequestWithSession, res: NextApiResponse) => {
const combinedData = { 
            ...userData, 
            guilds: guildsData 
        };
        
        if (req.session) {
          req.session.user = combinedData;
        }

        console.log("User data in session:", req.session.user); // This will specifically log the user data
    
        //res.status(200).json("works");
        res.redirect('/');

}
```

export default withSessionMiddleware(redirect);

_app.tsx

```
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"

function MyApp({Component, pageProps: { session, ...pageProps }, }: any) {


    <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
    </SessionProvider>
}
```

Implementing `getSession` function that's fetched with `useEffect` in Header and sets `userinfo` object globally. API call didn't work.